# Can people of two castes dine together?

Tags: caste-system, manu-smriti

In my state , there is tradition that in wedding or for that matter in any type of function , we invite only people from our own caste to the function , even if you have strong friendship with someone from other caste , that person can't be invited to the function .
( Even people of two upper castes don't invite each other . So, It has nothing to do with caste discrimination or untouchability)

i.e Only people of same caste can dine together .

(though this tradition is broken in cities and towns but it is still followed in villages . )

Is there any scriptural injunction from which this tradition has come ?

Comment: This is obviously true for cases like two apostate varnas. You should clarify you mean all castes/varna dine with all other castes/varna.